# WebSockets + PHP (Ratchet) login system

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I know how to make a secure login system with PHP including basics like hashing, salting and more complex security measures.

Recently I've been using Ratchet with WebSockets a lot. And I've been wondering if it is possible to create a secure register/login system using WebSockets.

1. User enters his data in form.
2. Data is validated and sanitized.
3. Password is hashed.
4. Everything is being sent to the server via WebSocket.
5. PHP stores it in MySQL database and salts the password's hash.
6. PHP returns a callback that registration finished via WebSocket.
7. User is granted access to the website.

I see it might work. My doubts are here: how secure is ws:// protocol? How to make sure that after logging in the user is the user that was logged? Some sort of sessions? Tokens?

Are there any frameworks/libraries/implementations of such a thing?

Questions are more out of plain curiosity over a new (kinda) piece of tech. If it doesn't work I'll just go for AJAX POST request. :)

Comment: Ratchet is a websocket server, not a web server. So I think there is no HTML forms

Comment: Data can be grabbed from HTML form by JavaScript and sent to Ratchet via WebSocket connection.

Comment: But you will rendere your initial HTML form with PHP no? Are you planning to do it also with javascript?

Comment: No. HTML is written in... HTML files. HTML is using JS here and there and where needed jQuery opens WebSocket connection and asks Ratchet to do some stuff for it.

Comment: I know HTML is written in HTML files, but commonly these HTML files are initially served by the WebServer. Why to send data from HTML from to Websocket server and then to webserver while you can directly keep the whole communication done by webserver. In other words, when you write `www.site.com/loginform` in browser address bar, browser sends an HTTP request to HTTP webserver that understand only HTTP and that return an intial HTML form.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Well I come from NodeJS way of things: I was thinking about some router that would send HTML after GET request on a specific address. But I don't really know if that is possible. Maybe making Ratchet on Apache makes sense (hardly since Apache has a blocking IO).

Comment: Ratchet is a WebSocket server, not a web server, so there is no PHP Session.  (Sort of -- A person can get cookies from the WS handshake and use that to associate with a user's web session.  However, you most certainly can NOT use the $_SESSION superglobal.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not possible to set up a secure authentication using any of the current WebSocket servers written in PHP.

They all lack TLS support.  (Even mine, though I do have an active development branch devoted to providing TLS support.)

Here is what is required for a secure authentication system with WebSockets:

**Basic PHP security first:**

1. Always transmit via TLS or some other secure transport system.
2. Use bcrypt or scrypt (or a future more secure system) to hash the password for storage in the database.  Even a stretched SHA256 password with a salt generated from a cryptographically random source is now considered insecure.
3. Authentication tokens (such as the session token created by PHP and stored in the session cookie) must be cryptographically unpredictable.
4. Authentication tokens must not be available to non-TLS traffic or client scripts.  (Strict enforcement of the Secure flag AND strict enforcement of the HttpOnly flag.)  This explicitly means that a user can not be securely authenticated unless they are in https: and wss: mode.
5. Session data must be stored in a secure directory or data storage on the server.
6. Reset the session token as part of authentication. Completely delete the data associated with the old session ID.

PHP's built in algorithm for generating session IDs uses /dev/urandom *if it is available* on your system. Windows users do not get cryptographically random session IDs, though because most WebSockets implementations would require a Posix environment, this isn't an issue.  If rolling your own session ID generator, use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, and remember that when it comes to security, it's a bad idea to roll your own.

Also, by default, the PHP session cookie does not have the Secure flag or the HttpOnly flag set.  Change these in your php.ini, and yes, this means that people can not authenticate anyone who is not using a secure connection -- but this is true anyways, since without TLS, you can not ensure that anyone is the same user from request to request, even if they're using the same session ID and same IP.

And, by default, the PHP session save path is your system's temp directory.  This is readable and writable by anyone.  Thus, any rogue process, regardless of escalated privileges, can access and alter any session data.  Least access means that only the web server user and, in the case of those of us using WebSockets, the WS server's user needs to access the session save path.

**WebSockets specific authentication:**

The session cookie is available to the WebSocket server during the handshake.  This includes when the cookie has the HttpOnly flag set. (Tested on latest publicly available Chrome on Windows.) (Secure flag not testable yet.  Give me a couple months as I get TLS working on my server.  If secure cookies are not available, or are available in a non-secure context, I'll be personally raising a holy stink with the browser vendors on your behalf.)

This means that someone who has an authenticated session can also be pre-authenticated on their WebSocket connection without having to pass data through the web document body (no need to embed the session ID in the HTML or in data in a script tag, which would then be re-transmitted through the open WS connection).

As for securely authenticating someone using WebSockets...  There is one huge caveat.

Because WebSocket servers have multiple users connected at the same time, the traditional sense of PHP sessions is broken.  *Which* session do we mean?

Thus, the $_SESSION superglobal MUST be strictly off limits, and the `session_...()` functions should be considered highly dangerous.  The only safe and meaningful session functions are the read-only version of `session_save_path()`, which tells you where to find the session files, `session_encode()`, and `session_decode()`.

To get the session data, you will need to read the session file, running its contents through `session_decode()`, and associating the results with the specific connection for that specific user.  You will also need to do this periodically, as the session data changes without warning.  To persist any data to the session, `session_encode()` is your friend, of course.  Since PHP doesn't care about race conditions on session data, you shouldn't either.  Just read the file, change the data, and write to the file, and it'll be all good.

And this brings us to the first real problem:  In order to have secure authentication, you need to reset the session token when the user is authenticated.  Since client side Javascript can't write to an HttpOnly cookie, you can't change the session ID on the client side.

The status of whether the user is authenticated can easily be updated within the existing session data, of course.  That's fairly trivial.  However, because we need a new session ID *before* we persist the new authentication state, and that new session ID must be valid for all of the client's connections immediately, we can't completely perform secure authentication through a WebSocket connection.

A possible work-around to use as much WebSockets as possible (once a PHP WS server supports TLS, that is):

- Client sends login information to the server through the WebSocket connection.
- Server responds back with a cryptographically random token.
- Client responds back with a salt through the WS connection, and with a hashed and salted version of the token through an AJAX request.
- Server verifies the salt matches, and using the AJAX request's script, calls `session_regenerate_id(true)`, and returns any appropriate response (just so long as the `set-cookie:` header is set).
- Server updates its internal mapping to the user's new session ID.
- Server discards the one-time token completely, and naturally logs any attempted use of any invalid one-time tokens.

(It might be worth it to implement a true Diffie-Hellman exchange to set up a true secure shared secret.  I am not a security expert; the above algorithm may not be as secure as I think it is, though because it would already be in two TLS tunnels, it should be secure. (The https: tunnel is separate and distinct from the wss: tunnel, thus there is a need to confirm information sent through one tunnel matches information sent through the other, but should not require secrecy in addition to that already afforded by TLS.))

**Bottom line:**

Yes, security is hard to get right.  But it's worth it.

Comment: Now this is an answer I was hoping for! Very informative, thanks. :)