# Authentication through WebSocket

Tags: php, authentication, websocket, ratchet, reactphp

I'm using Ratchet (based on ReactPHP) to host a WebSocket server which needs the users Oauth token for connecting to Twitter. How should I authenticate the user on it safely?

Comment: How would you authenticate someone safely if you used HTTP? Hint: the answer is the same.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370762/websockets-php-ratchet-login-system